# How to convert nvarchar string mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss to datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a nvarchar column with dates formatted like this: "04/18/2021 13:04:15" (without quotes). I want to change this column to be datetime and migrate all of it data. I've looked for format codes and figured out, that closest code to my variant is U.S (101). So I tried to

```
UPDATE DropPhotos
SET CreationDateTime = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), CONVERT(DateTime, CreationDateTime, 101))
ALTER TABLE DropPhotos
ALTER COLUMN CreationDateTime DateTime
```

But I get error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not be storing date/time values as strings in the database.  Of course, what you are doing is fine, if the next step is to alter the column to be `datetime` (or something similar).

Second, you clearly have bad data.  So, use `try_convert()` to find it:

```
select CreationDateTime
from DropPhotos
where try_convert(DateTime, CreationDateTime, 101) is null and
      CreationDateTime is not null;
```

You'll need to figure out what to do about that bad values.  If `NULL` is acceptable, then just use `try_convert()` in your original logic:

```
SET CreationDateTime = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), TRY_CONVERT(DateTime, CreationDateTime, 101))
```

Comment: With you query I found out that I have some dates in different format: 26.04.2021 06:09:03

Can I handle both of it at the same time?

Comment: @Fallingsappy . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, with clear sample data and desired results.  This answers the question you asked here.

Answer (score 1):

If the formats you have are just the 2 formats you have listed:

```
 Select t.CreationDateTime
      , us_101_format = try_convert(datetime, t.CreationDateTime, 101)
      , german_104_format = try_convert(datetime, t.CreationDateTime, 104)
      , dt.CreationDateTime
   From (Values ('04/18/2021 13:04:15'), ('26.04.2021 06:09:03'))                       As t(CreationDateTime)
  Cross Apply (Values (coalesce(try_convert(datetime, t.CreationDateTime, 101)
                              , try_convert(datetime, t.CreationDateTime, 104))))       As dt(CreationDateTime)
  --Where dt.CreationDateTime Is Null;
  Where dt.CreationDateTime Is Not Null;
```

If you also have some formatted as 'mm.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss' then you are going to have a much harder time determining which format to use for that entry.

If you have another format that is unique you can add to the list of converts for that format.